# pyautogui isn't activating windows with .click()

Tags: python, pyautogui

When trying to, for example, use pyautogui to type an url into a web browser, I can't seem to type anything outside my IDE

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.click(300, 80)
pyautogui.typewrite('Hello World')
```

Even just using .click() it doesn't seem to activate the window. I'm on MacOS Catalina.

Answer (score 1):

Add clicks=2 to your click call. The first click will activate the window. Other than this I don't think Pyautogui offers a way to do that.

Comment: Still not working for me, but I've definitely seen it done. I'm currently following Automate the Boring Stuff. I'm concerned that Catalina has an issue with this but I'm not sure. Haven't come across any answers on it.

Comment: @SuitsAndPajamas I just tested pyautogui on Catalina and it works perfectly fine, a single click is enough to get focus and click into the input box.

Comment: I actually just tried clicking the icon first to see if that activates the window for me and it does. For some reason just clicking the window itself doesn't. But if it works for you I must be missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to run the commands jointly in one line.

```
pyautogui.click(300, 80); pyautogui.typewrite('Hello World')
```

This technique was mentioned in the Automate the Boring Stuff here

> Notice how placing two commands on the same line, separated by a semicolon, keeps the interactive shell from prompting you for input between running the two instructions. This prevents you from accidentally bringing a new window into focus between the click() and write() calls, which would mess up the example.
>
> https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter20/

Answer (score -1):

The above methods could work, but I would recommend running your .py file as Administrator would help solve your issue.